# How do I use tkinter Spinboxs to move through a set of choices in a List

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make a tkinter spinbox iterate through a list of times.

```
import tkinter as tk
TimeChoices=["00:00","00:30","04:00","08:30"]
root=tk.Tk()
time=tk.StringVar()
spintimeselector=tk.Spinbox(root,textvariable=time,TimeChoices)
spintimeselector.pack()


root.mainloop
```

I am unsure on how to go about this, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Follow this pattern [tkinterbook/spinbox](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/spinbox.htm)

Comment: This isn't helpful, as stated in the question, I am trying to make the spinbox iterate through the times in the list whenever the spinbox is spun. I am very aware of the from_=0 functionality found in a Spinbox. Quite obviously this wouldn't work for the times.

Comment: Didn't get your point, your given code is invalid. Fixing this, no `from_=` is needed, it shows `00:00...08:30` well.  [edit] your Question and show the errors you get.

Comment: On my side it works as intended - just fix positional argument (use `values`) after the named one in your code (as @stovfl mentioned that your code is invalid).

Comment: @CommonSense Could you please post working code as an answer. I keep running into the "positional argument follows keywords" error